# com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MysqlSyntaxErrorException:Access denied for user "@'local host' to database 'mysql'

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, netbeans-7

`com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MysqlSyntaxErrorException:Access denied for user "@'local host' to database 'mysql'`

This is my problem. I get this error every time I try to do the execution.

I have already tried this:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES 
ON GUEST_BOOK.* TO 'root'@'%' 
IDENTIFIED BY 'D7n()st1234' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Comment: Show us your code for connecting to the database, including the connection URL.

Answer (score 1):

You are connecting as '' user (as in zero length string) you need to specify the username correctly

Answer (score 0):

connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL,USERNAME,PASSWORD);
make sure the "USERNAME" and the "PASSWORD" is not forgetton